# How to test the stability of internet connection for this particular scenerio

Tags: networking, 3g

I work for a company and we have a device that we are installing in small shops for their payment transactions. This device uses internet connection as the primary connection and in case internet goes down, it fails to 3G connection. During this time there is a downtime for few minutes

But we are having issues, where customers are calling us and says that their site goes down repeatedly throughout the day. When we look into our logs we see that our device has indeed failed over and back a number of times from primary to 3G and back to primary. We advise them that they need to check with ISP and make sure there is no internet drops.

Often customer say that they have consulted with ISP and they seem to say there are no issues from their end.

The only other possible reason that I can think of as to why the device keeps falling is due to faulty cabling. Are there are other way that we can test out that the problem is to do with Internet and not our device?

Comment: Your device logs should have the best clues - if you can share a sanitised version that does not give an confidential info then you will probably have better luck here. As an aside, the 3G connection itself should not really take 'minutes' to set up so this would probably be worth looking at also - there may be something in your set up protocol which could optimised to speed up any handover if their are failures.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps you ought to expand the test routines included in the device, assuming the device has the memory capacity and/or libraries and computing power available.

For example, does your device determine the Internet is down only if it cannot reach a certain IP destination? If so, you may want to expand this by 1) testing to ensure timeouts aren't too short due to upstream congestion, 2) testing another known location such as Google's DNS server 8.8.8.8 when the intended destination IP fails, and 3) testing the internal gateway to determine if the ISP modem/router has rebooted for some reason.

Comment: Do you know the router model used to connect to ISP?

Comment: Router model varies from site to site...comcast, centurylink etc.